# Which version of Silverlight Supports Task parallel Library

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

Though TPL is widely accepted as a feature of C# 4.0 , but heard that it is not supported on SL4, but SL5.

Could not find any solid evidence of it.

So why the do MicroSoft implemented a feature in WPF but not Silverlight, though both sl4 and wpf4 released around same time.

Comment: [Task:s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.95).aspx) are implemented in SL5, whereas [Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) and associated classes are not. The obvious reason why this was left out of Silverlight is compactness; to keep the Silverlight runtime compact various functionality had to be omitted.

Comment: @LexLi, If ,am not wrong ,You meant Support for SL5 has expired this month?

Comment: Support for SL4 has expired.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson No, the obvious reason is laziness.

Answer (score 2):

If you need TCL in Silverlight 4 you can add the "[Microsoft.Bcl](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)" and "Microsoft.Bcl.Async"   nuGet packages to your project.

They implement part of what TCL delivers in .net.
More info can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/)

Don't forget you have to use the `TaskEx` class instead.

Hoped it helped.