# Keeping track of asynchronous loading vs thread safety?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, thread-safety, loading

When initializing the UI in my C# Silverlight application, I make several asynchronous calls to different services.  While doing all the loading asynchronously is very nice and speedy, there are still times when I need some step of the loading to happen at the very end.

On some views in the past, I had implemented a "loading list" mechanic to help me keep track of loading, and guarantee the order of whatever actions are picky about when they fire.  Here is a very simplified example:

```
private List<string> _loadingList = new List<string>();

// Called to begin the loading process
public void LoadData(List<long> IDs){
    foreach(long id in IDs){
        DoSomethingToLoadTheID(id);
        _loadingList.Add(id.ToString());
    }
}

// Called every time an ID finishes loading
public void LoadTheIDCompleted(object sender, ServiceArgs e){
    UseTheLoadedData(e);

    _loadingList.Remove(id.ToString());
    if(_loadingList.Count == 0)
        LoadDataFinally();
}

// Must be called after all other loading is completed
public void LoadDataFinally(){
    ImportantFinishingTouches();
}
```

This thing works for my purposes, and I haven't experienced any problems with it yet.  But I am not as confident about my knowledge of thread safety as I'd like to be, so I'd like to ask a couple of questions:

- **Is there any way this kind of thing can mess up catastrophically?**
- **Is there a better way to accomplish this same functionality?**

(I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and .NET Framework 4.5.51209, and Silverlight 5.0)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way this kind of thing can mess up catastrophically?

Depending on what you are doing, absolutely.  First, you are accessing `List(of T)` from multiple threads.  You should be using `ConcurrentList<T>` instead as it is thread safe.  Remember that ANY class (including .NET framework components) being accessed/modified by multiple threads must be thread safe.  MSDN indicates which framework components are and are not.

> Is there a better way to accomplish this same functionality?

I don't see anywhere in your code where multiple threads are being used, but I assume that what you are trying to do is:

- Get a list of IDs
- Run some long-running or CPU-bound process for each ID
- Remove that ID from the list of IDs

Depending on the nature of what you are doing with each ID, the approach may be different.  For instance, if the work is CPU-bound then you could use Tasks/TPL:

```
// Using TPL
var ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};
Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => DoSomething(id)); // Invokes DoSomething on each ID in the list in parallel
```

Or if you need fine-grained control of the order that things execute...

```
var ids = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3, 4};

TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var id in ids)
{
    tasks.Add(factory.StartNew(() => DoSomething(id)));  // executes async and keeps track of the task in the list
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // waits till everything is done

tasks.Clear();

foreach (var id in ids)
{
    tasks.Add(factory.StartNew(() => DoSomethingElse(id)));  // executes async and keeps track of the task in the list
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray()); // Wait till all DoSomethingElse is done

// etc.
```

Now if the work you are doing is IO bound (eg. making webservice calls where you have to wait for slow responses), you should look into [Asynchronous Programming with async and await (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

There are a lot of ways to handle multi-threading, and sometimes figuring out the right way is part of the challenge (async/await vs. tasks vs. semaphores vs. background workers vs. etc.).

Comment: Yeah I didn't put the actual threading stuff in my example due to it being very bulky.  The project uses WCF services, and unfortunately I don't know much about how those work except you start them with a call to a generated *ServiceName*Async() method, and you get the results by subscribing to a generated *ServiceName*Completed event.  As much as I'd like to be using TPL I am not sure how it would fit into that pattern, which is all over the application.

Comment: I'm also under the impression that Silverlight doesn't have access to anything in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, and as far as I can tell from a google search there's no such thing as a ConcurrentList<T>.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396139/which-version-of-silverlight-supports-task-parallel-library

Comment: not sure why you posted that, I've looked and found that TPL is indeed in my version of Silverlight, was just pointing out that ConcurrentList or ConcurrentBag or whatever were not.